# I am getting type errors when I run 'docker build --no-cache -t chat-server .'

Tags: typescript, docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile in the root of my express server:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /usr/src/server

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is my .dockerignore file

```
node_modules
dist
Dockerfile
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "@types/socket.io": "^3.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "prisma": "^4.12.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.12.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.6.1"
  }
}
```

When I run the `docker build --no-cache -t chat-server .` command, I get this output:

```
[+] Building 11.5s (11/11) FINISHED                                 
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 185B                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 68B                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18     1.0s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io    0.0s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:18@sha256:ee0a21d64211d  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 152.14kB                          0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /usr/src/server                       0.0s
 => [3/6] COPY package*.json ./                                0.0s
 => [4/6] RUN npm install                                      7.4s
 => [5/6] COPY . .                                             0.0s 
 => ERROR [6/6] RUN npm run build                              2.8s
------
 > [6/6] RUN npm run build:
#11 0.509 
#11 0.509 > server@1.0.0 build
#11 0.509 > tsc
#11 0.509 
#11 2.763 src/controllers/conversationsController.ts(63,12): error TS7006: Parameter 'participant' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#11 2.763 src/controllers/conversationsController.ts(105,10): error TS7006: Parameter 'participant' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#11 2.763 src/controllers/conversationsController.ts(160,41): error TS7006: Parameter 'conversation' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#11 2.763 src/controllers/conversationsController.ts(170,12): error TS7006: Parameter 'participant' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#11 2.763 src/controllers/messagesController.ts(44,16): error TS7006: Parameter 'participant' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#11 2.763 src/controllers/messagesController.ts(45,19): error TS7006: Parameter 'participant' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

IDK why I am getting these type errors. When I run `npm run build` by itself in the terminal, everything works fine.

I have tried not copying the package-lock.json in the Dockerfile.

Comment: What are you copying with the command `COPY . .`, what is in that directory?

Comment: The 'COPY . .' command copies over the project files into the container's working directory

Comment: It seems like the build is complaining about a couple of specific lines in your source; what do those lines look like?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `tsconfig.json` file in you project, which you aren't transferring as part of the Docker build? The error is provoked by the `noImplicitAny` flag, which is also activated when running TypeScript in [strict mode](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny).

Comment: I do have a tsconfig.json file in the root of the project. The 'COPY . .' should be copying the tsconfig into the working directory.

Comment: Could you insert a print in the Dockerfile to check that the resulting directory structure is as intended?

Comment: Could there be something with your NODE_ENV variable? Perhaps some dependencies, which are not being installed as intended on Docker?

Comment: Oh, another thing: I can see you are using Prisma. Are the mentioned parameters by any chance something related to your Prisma Client? You would usually regenerate it as part of your Dockerfile.